# Select Count Top Inner Join and Where Clause in SQL

Tags: sql-server

This is my Query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 tablestudentanswer.examid, 
             tablestudentanswer.studentid, 
             tablestudentanswer.itemno, 
             tablestudentanswer.studentanswer, 
             tablescore.score 
FROM   tablestudentanswer 
       INNER JOIN tablescore 
               ON tablestudentanswer.studentid = tablescore.studentid 
                  AND tablestudentanswer.examid = tablescore.examid 
WHERE  tablestudentanswer.examid = 1 
       AND tablestudentanswer.itemno = 1 
ORDER  BY tablescore.score ASC
```

It returns this table:

```
ExamID  StudentID  ItemNo  StudentAnswer   Score
1006    1          1       A               25
1005    1          2       B               30
1004    1          3       A               35
```

What i want to do is it will return 2 if StudentAnswer='A' and 1 if StudentAnswer='B'
Guys there is nothing wrong with my query on top. What i am asking is what should I add in that query.

I have this which  in my mind should return 2 but its an error.

```
Select COUNT(*) From (
Select Top 3 TableStudentAnswer.ExamID, TableStudentAnswer.StudentID, TableStudentAnswer.ItemNo, TableStudentAnswer.StudentAnswer, TableScore.Score 
from TableStudentAnswer
Inner join TableScore on TableStudentAnswer.StudentID=TableScore.StudentID and TableStudentAnswer.ExamID=TableScore.ExamID
where TableStudentAnswer.ExamID=1 and TableStudentAnswer.ItemNo=1
Order By TableScore.Score Asc) where TableStudentAnswer.StudentAnswer = 'A'
```

It should return:

```
2
```

Please help me!

Comment: Please clarify your requirement, what's wrong with the query?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query the problem is I dont know what to add on that query to get my desired output. which is 2 if StudentAnswer='A' and 1 if StudentAnswer='B'.

Comment: Please, to prevent further confusion - add the result set you actually want, ie. all the rows and columns it should have and their values. That is usually the best way to make sure we're answering what you want to know the answer to :)

Comment: I updated it please i need help.

Answer (score 2):

Will this do?

```
SELECT TOP 3 tablestudentanswer.examid, 
             tablestudentanswer.studentid, 
             tablestudentanswer.itemno, 
             tablestudentanswer.studentanswer, 
             tablescore.score,
             case 
              when tablestudentanswer.studentanswer = 'A' then 2
              when tablestudentanswer.studentanswer = 'B' then 1
              else NULL
             end as [MyColumn]
FROM   tablestudentanswer 
       INNER JOIN tablescore 
               ON tablestudentanswer.studentid = tablescore.studentid 
                  AND tablestudentanswer.examid = tablescore.examid 
WHERE  tablestudentanswer.examid = 1 
       AND tablestudentanswer.itemno = 1 
ORDER  BY tablescore.score ASC
```

Your question is a bit unclear. Perhaps you want the amount of answers for each?

```
count(1) over (partition by tablestudentanswer.studentanswer)
```

This will give you a column with the amount of all the answers with the given `studentanswer` to each of the rows in the result set. However, note that this could be quite slow. If you can, you're better off using a normal `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you would like the query to return the number of answers? If so, using COUNT may help.

```
SELECT   tablestudentanswer.studentid,
         tablestudentanswer.studentanswer
         COUNT(1) AS NumberOfAnswers
FROM   tablestudentanswer 
   INNER JOIN tablescore 
           ON tablestudentanswer.studentid = tablescore.studentid 
              AND tablestudentanswer.examid = tablescore.examid 
GROUP BY tablestudentanswer.studentid, tablestudentanswer.studentanswer
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

By the way, why does your result table doesn't consist of itemno even though you have it in your SELECT statement?

Comment: I am sorry i forget to put the item no

Comment: The following query should do the work?

    Select COUNT(1) From (
    Select Top 3 StudentAnswer
    from TableStudentAnswer
    Inner join TableScore on TableStudentAnswer.StudentID=TableScore.StudentID and TableStudentAnswer.ExamID=TableScore.ExamID
    where TableStudentAnswer.ExamID=1 and TableStudentAnswer.ItemNo=1) where StudentAnswer = 'A'

Comment: My bad. I forgot that we need to give a name to the table first.

 Thus the correct query should be Select COUNT(1) From ( Select Top 3 StudentAnswer from TableStudentAnswer Inner join TableScore on TableStudentAnswer.StudentID=TableScore.StudentID and TableStudentAnswer.ExamID=TableScore.ExamID where TableStudentAnswer.ExamID=1 and TableStudentAnswer.ItemNo=1) AS Ref where Ref.StudentAnswer = 'A'